# Intel display glitches in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, drivers, intel-graphics

I am getting intermittent graphics glitches in small rectangular areas as shown.  If I move my mouse the glitch will shift or disappear.  Is there a setting I can change to fix this?  My system:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz × 8
- Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2)

[image: glitch]

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `dpkg -l *microcode* | grep ii`. It's possible that it doesn't give an answer. If that's the case, then `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode` and then `reboot`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that this occurs on both external monitor and built in display @anx.

`intel-microcode 3.20151106.1 amd64        Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs`

`intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20151106.1).` @heynnema